# SAGA tool 'Relative Heights and Slope Positions' - What do results tell me?

Tags: qgis, dem, saga, srtm

I am currently trying to get in morphometry, using the SRTM 30m DEM. I was recommended to test the SAGA mudule 'Relative Heights and Slope Positions' (http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/ta_morphometry_14.html) in QGIS.
It runs smoothly and I have first results, but I am a bit lost in understanding what results tell me. Does anybody of you have expert knowledge to explain what the following mean?

- Slope height (values ~0-700)
- Valley depth (values ~0-600)
- Normalized height (values ~0-1)
- Standardized height (values ~0-3000)
- Mid slope position (values ~-0,00001-1)

Input options w, t and e are also not clear to me.

If anybody of you has an idea or an idea where to find information, I would be very happy.

Comment: There is [paper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/HBPL19/hbpl19_05.pdf/download?use_mirror=kent) which explains some of the terms you describe (nomarlized/standardized heights and mid slope positions). Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Thank you very much! One of the authors is also the module developer. I already contacted him on Research Gate. Great help from your side.

Comment: Most welcome buddy but it seems you did all the work in contacting the developer, kudos! Perhaps you could post what you learnt as an **answer** so that it could help those in similar situations? :)

Comment: Yes, definitely will do that as soon as I get an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, the answer from the developers of the tool, who kindly allowed me to forward the answer here. I translate and do my best to reproduce what I learnt from Dr. Conrad:

The only expected input-dataset is the DEM. The tool runs an interative procedure which works with relative relief-position. The same procedure is used to calculate 
- the vertical distance below a terrain culmination (peak, ridge,...)
- distance above the terrain minima (valley, depression,...).
This is in the first step based on a drainage-oriented calculation of vertical distances ( based on Freeman, T.G.,1991: Calculating catchment
area with divergent flow based on a regular grid. Computers and Geoscience, Bd. 17, 3, 413-422. [hope this is the correct publication]) and is afterwards refined iteratively to eliminate effects of watersheds.

Options W, T, E control the iterative process:
'W: The parameter weights the influence of catchment size on relative
elevation (inversely proportional).
T: The parameter controls the amount by which a maximum in the
neighbourhood of a cell is taken over into the cell (considering the
local slope between the cells). The smaller 't' and/or the smaller the
slope, the more of the maximum value is taken over into the cell. This
results in a greater generalization/smoothing of the result. The greater
't' and/or the higher the slope, the less is taken over into the cell
and the result will show a more irregular pattern caused by small
changes in elevation between the cells.
E: The parameter controls the position of relative height maxima as a
function of slope.'

After determination of relevant distances (below/ above), these are used to calculate standardized elevation (0= low; 1= top) and based on that we receive standardized elevation and mid slope position.

Reference: - Boehner, J. and Selige, T. (2006): Spatial prediction of soil
attributes using terrain analysis and climate regionalisation. In:
Boehner, J., McCloy, K.R., Strobl, J. [Ed.]: SAGA - Analysis and
Modelling Applications, Goettinger Geographische Abhandlungen,
Goettingen: 13-28. (find this online on the saga homepage)

To cite saga: Conrad, O., Bechtel, B., Bock, M., Dietrich, H., Fischer, E.,
Gerlitz, L., Wehberg, J., Wichmann, V., and Böhner, J.: System for
Automated Geoscientific Analyses (SAGA) v. 2.1.4, Geosci. Model Dev., 8,
1991-2007, doi:10.5194/gmd-8-1991-2015, 2015. Available online for free http://www.geosci-model-dev.net/8/1991/2015/gmd-8-1991-2015.html

Comment: +1, great for coming back and posting this from the developers!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is great, but I had some difficulty interpreting the use of the *t* parameter. The SAGA discussion forum has a [similar explanation](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/c57eb4aa/?limit=25#7bd4), with further explanation by the developers on what *t* does. In case of trouble with that link, I wanted to include it here (too long to put in a comment):

> I will try to provide an explanation, based on how Jürgen Böhner
>   explained it to me. The parameter "t" controls the amount by which a
>   maximum in the neighbourhood of a cell is taken over into the cell
>   (considering the slope between the cells). The smaller "t" and/or the
>   smaller the slope, the more of the maximum value is taken over into
>   the cell. You can observe this by a greater generalization/smoothing
>   of the result. The greater "t" and/or the higher the slope, the less
>   is taken over into the cell and you will observe a more irregular
>   pattern caused by small changes in elevation between the cells.
>
> Consider a flat and broad valley bottom. There are typically some
>   cells on the valley bottom which are just a little bit higher (a few
>   centimetres) than their surrounding cells. These cells would have only
>   themselves as catchment area and not the whole catchment of the valley
>   side. This "noise" in the DEM is hydrologically irrelevant but would
>   cause a very high spatial variation of the computed values which is
>   not observable in nature (a small elevation difference of 1cm would
>   not cause a "dry" soil column at this position).
>
> As you already have read Böhner & Selige (2006), have a look at
>   equation 01. It shows the same principle, here with catchment area
>   calculation for the SAGA Wetness Index. The parameter "t" is fixed
>   here (15). So simply exchange 15 by "t" in the equation and you have
>   the formula used by the "Relative Heights and Slope Positions" tool to
>   determine the amount by which a maximum from the neighbourhood is
>   taken over into the currently processed cell.